# Solid angle of human field of vision

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, solid-angle

This is a question about solid angles.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view), the central/binocular field of human vision is about $2\pi/3$ in the horizontal plane, and $\pi/3$ in the vertical axis.

*Roughly*, this tells me that we can see a "rectangle" that is two-thirds of the horizontal extent and one-third of the vertical extent.

Does this mean that we can see clearly a solid angle of two-ninths of $2\pi$ steradians? Or does something else happen with the geometry because it's spherical.

Comment: This is a question more about medicine than about math I think.

Comment: @Arthur no, it's not. I am happy to assume for the question that the field of vision angles are correct. I am interested in solid angles.

Comment: The way I read it, you're asking about whether our field of vision is more like a rectangular cone or like an elliptical cone. I might have misunderstood, though.

Comment: @Arthur For the purposes of this question, we can assume a rectangular cone... the question is how does that rectangle give a solid angle measurement.

Comment: That's fair then. I just misunderstood.

Comment: This Wikipedia article may help: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle. Basically, the solid angle is the area of a spherical cap divided by the radius squared. Moreover, we don't really see a rectangular box with our eyes. I would imagine that it's more like an ellipse when calculating the projected area. Technically, $\Omega=A/r^2$, where $A$ is the area projected on a sphere. In your case, we don't want to think about $r$, so we can express this as $\Omega=4\pi A/A_{max}$, in other words expressing the area as a fraction of that of a full sphere.

Answer (score 0):

From Calculus(Robert A. Adams), page 978:  Suppose the viewer is at point P. Two rays from P determines an angle at P whose measure in radians is equal to the length of the arc of the circle of radius $1$ with center at P lying between the two rays.Similarly, an arbitrary shaped half-cone K with vertex at P determines a solid angle at P whose measure in steradians is the area of sphere of radius $1$ with center at P lying within K. For example , the first octant of $\mathbb R^3$ is haf- cone with vertex at the origin.It determines a solid angle at origin measuring

$4\pi \times \frac 18=\frac{\pi}2$

since the area of the unit sphere is $4\pi$.

Now, coefficient $c=\frac 18$ represent $\frac{\pi}2$ on x axis and $\frac {\pi}2$ on y axis. We may use simple proportion to find our coefficient:

On x axis: $$\frac {\frac{2\pi}3}{\frac{\pi}2}= \frac 43$$

On y axis: $$\frac {\frac{\pi}3}{\frac{\pi}2}= \frac 23$$

So we may write:

$c= \frac 23\times \frac 43\times\frac 18=\frac 19$

So the measure of the solid angle is:

$\frac{\pi}2\times \frac 19=\frac{4\pi}{9}$.

If you want to consider an Ellipsoid instead of a sphere, you may use the following formula for the surface area:

$$S\approx 4\pi\big(\frac{(ab)^{1.6}+(ac)^{1.6}+(bc)^{1.6}}3\big)^{\frac1{1.6}}$$

What we have is the hight of the viewer which is c. for a and be we take  arbitrary values.

Comment: Surely $4/3$ not $3/2$?

Comment: @JPMcCarthy, you are right, sorry for the error. Corrected.

Comment: This is corroborating the $2/9$ in the question.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy, You said in question "two third of $\2pi$ which is $\frac{\4\pi}3$

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here. I don't see that in my question.